# wordpress rss feed - getting all entries for a category

Tags: wordpress, rss

I know how to retrieve the rss feed from a category in wp, namely to add `/feed` behind the category name. However when I do this, not all entries from that feed are included in the rss.

I want to know `what variable governs the the length of the rss feed` (**programatically as well as in the back end admin**), and how can I include all entries from a category.

UPDATE: I would also like to know if a feed length could be set indiviually for each category.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

It's in the admin panel under the reading tab.

Set it to something like 999

Comment: Is there a way to set it for each feed individually? Like ?feed=rss2&size=50